# Quasar Framework (VueJS) - "UI" compiled with errors (If import web3)

Tags: vue.js, ethereum, web3js, quasar

I use Quasar CLI version 1.2.1 and library web3 version ^1.5.2

it's an error when i use:

```
import Web3 from 'web3'
```

Log Error:

> App • Chaining "UI" Webpack config  App •  WAIT  • Compiling of "UI"
> in progress...  App •  DONE  • "UI" compiled with errors • 6809ms
>
> App •  ERROR  •  UI  in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve imported dependency "stream" Did you
> forget to install it? You can run: yarn add stream
>
> App •  ERROR  •  UI  in ./node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve imported dependency "crypto" Did you
> forget to install it? You can run: yarn add crypto
>
> App •  ERROR  •  UI  in
> ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/account.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve imported dependency "assert" Did you
> forget to install it? You can run: yarn add assert
>
> App •  ERROR  •  UI  in
> ./node_modules/swarm-js/node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve imported dependency "crypto" Did you
> forget to install it? You can run: yarn add crypto
>
> App •  ERROR  •  UI  in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve imported dependency "crypto" Did you
> forget to install it? You can run: yarn add crypto
>
> App •  ERROR  •  UI  in
> ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve imported dependency "http" Did you
> forget to install it? You can run: yarn add http
>
> App •  ERROR  •  UI  in
> ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve imported dependency "https" Did you
> forget to install it? You can run: yarn add https
>
> App •  ERROR  •  UI  in
> ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve imported dependency "http" Did you
> forget to install it? You can run: yarn add http
>
> App •  ERROR  •  UI  in
> ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve imported dependency "https" Did you
> forget to install it? You can run: yarn add https
>
> App •  ERROR  •  UI  in
> ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve imported dependency "os" Did you
> forget to install it? You can run: yarn add os
>
> App •  COMPILATION FAILED  • Please check the log above for details.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a nodejs module in the browser.

If you carefully read the [documentation](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js) it says:

> **In the Browser**
>
> Use the prebuilt dist/web3.min.js

So what you would need to do is: `import Web3 from 'web3/dist/web3.min.js'`

Answer (score 0):

Since Quasar is using webpack-v5 You must install Nodejs polyfills

read the docs here

https://quasar.dev/start/upgrade-guide#webpack-v5